# Tabula.py groups multiple columns in a single column

Tags: tabula

I'm trying to parse the below table using Tabula  with the following code:

```
data= tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages= [16, 17], pandas_options= {'header': 2}, multiple_tables= False)
```

but it bundles some of the columns together as can be seen when checking the resulting Dataframe columns:

```
Index(['Unnamed: 0', 'P1 P2 P3 P4', 'P5', 'P6', 'C1 C2 C3 C4 C5', 'C6', 'C7',
       'C8', 'D1 D2 D3 D4 D5', 'D6', 'D7', 'M1 M2 M3 M4 M5 M6', 'M7', 'M8',
       'M9'],
      dtype='object')
```

I tried to specify the names of the columns in pandas options as `col_names = ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', ..., 'M8', 'M9']`, so the code whould be"

```
data= tabula.read_pdf(pdf_path, pages= [16, 17], pandas_options= {'header': 2, 'names': col_names}, multiple_tables= False)
```

but then I get the following `Error` :

```
CSVParseError: Error failed to create DataFrame with different column tables.
Try to set `multiple_tables=True`or set `names` option for `pandas_options`. 
, caused by ParserError('Too many columns specified: expected 30 and found 15')
```

Any help with that, please?

[image: Table]

Comment: From the `Error failed to create DataFrame with different column tables..` it looks like Tabula is detecting 2 (probably a vertical split at D6 or D7) tables from your input. As stated in the error, try setting the multiple tables to True and see what is has, you may have to do a pd inner join concat on the output

Comment: I tried to set multiple tables to True, but still get an error saying ```ValueError: 30 columns passed, passed data had 15 columns```. I think it doesn't recognise some of the vertical splits, thus grouping some of the columns and the result is the 15 columns mentioned in the error